# Nonlinear ODE system solver (Runge-Kutta)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, nonlinear-system, runge-kutta-methods

I`m trying to solve the following nonlinear-system(please see the pic attached) but I´m truly lost.

[EQUATIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXkRm.png)

I need to create one method called solve_prec, which solves the system. I dont know how to use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp in this case.

Note: T (x=0) = 1, and the domain of integration is (0, -0.25). Moreover energy method refers to e, pressure method refers to p. Finally $\rho$ is den, e0 = energy(1,1)  and p0 = pressure(1,1)
Thanks in advance!!

```
class eos_gamma_c():

 def __init__(self, gamma=5/3.0, M0 = 10, P0 = 0.0001, k = 0.0001):
  self.gamma = gamma
  self.M0 = M0
  self.P0 = P0
  self.k  = k
  self.cv = 1./self.gamma/(self.gamma-1.)
  return

def energy(self, tem, den):
 return self.cv*tem 

def pressure(self, tem, den):
 return den*tem/self.gamma

def solve_prec(self, tem, den):
 ene0 = self.energy(1,1)
 pre0 = self.pressure(1,1)
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You would need to define what ${\cal P}_0$ is, some kind of polynomial or just a constant? It seems that it would help numerical stability to make $U=T^4$ the primary dependent function, compute $T=\sqrt[4]{U}$ where necessary.

Comment: @LutzLehmann its just a constant. I can manually organize the equation and put ρ in eq(23) with only dependence by T. Then I introduce this result in (22) and solve (in fact I did it). However I need a generalist code that, for any definition of e(T,ρ) and p(T,ρ) can solve the system.